# Continue output after parent child termination , i am unable to perform the operation

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, fork, parent-child

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void sigusr(int iSig)   //SIGUSER are the user defined signals
  {
        if (iSig == SIGUSR1)
        {
                printf("Received SIGUSR1 signal, going to sleep for 2 seconds\n");
                sleep(2);
                
        }
  }
int main ()
  {
        int pid;
        signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0)   //Parent process created
        {
                for(int i=0; i<=1000;i++)
                {
                        printf("%d\n",i);
                    usleep(70);
                }
        }
        else           //Child process created
        {
                sleep(5);
                kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
                exit(0);
        }
   }
```

Create 2 processes, a parent and a child using fork().
The parent prints the value of ‘i’ from 0 to 1000 and then exits.
Meanwhile  the  child  process sleeps for 5 seconds after it is created,
sends a SIGUSR1 signal to the parent and  then  exits.
The  parent should  catch  that  signal,  print on  standard output “Received SIGUSR1 signal,
going to sleep for 2 seconds”, sleep for two seconds and then continueprinting the numbers.
But i am unable to continue the process after child process termination.

Comment: I'm not sure printf() and sleep() are reentrant. Do not call them from within sig handler. Set a variable instead and check that variable from within the print loop.

Comment: quite a lot of things are making problems. you don't wait for the child in the father, and what id the value of pid within the child? BTW printf is not signal safe.

Answer (score 0):

For me everything works fine if I increase `usleep` time, without it parent process terminates before child process send signal.
The problem is with `kill` call, `else` statement is executed only in child process, so it means that `pid` value is `0`, `kill` with `pid` `0` sends signal to whole group, in this case to parent and a child, you should change it to

```
kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @complikator 's answer, you shoudl print and sleep outside the signal handler.
There are remaining questions like "main finishes before the signal is received", but this is really depending on you use case...

would look like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


volatile static bool called = false;

static void sigusr(int iSig)
{
    called = true;
}

void check_signaled(void) {
    if (called) {
        called = false;
        printf("Received SIGUSR1 signal, going to sleep for 2 seconds\n");
        sleep(2);
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0)   //Parent process created
    {
        signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr);
        for(int i=0; i<=1000;i++)
        {
            check_signaled(); /* if signal come while iterating */
            printf("%d\n",i);
            usleep(70);
        }
        wait(NULL); /* wait child completion */
        check_signaled(); /* signal may happen "too late" */
    }
    else           //Child process created
    {
        sleep(1);
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
    }
}
```